# codeigniter on and where combination

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Table `user` left join table `personal_record` then join table `activity`.

---

`user` table:id ...

`personal_record` table: user.id, activity.id, confirm_time...

`activity`: id, time, delete_time...

note: time means hours spent on this activity, 8 etc.

---

Before `user` join `personal_record`, some of `persanoal_record` rows need to be filtered as `personal_record` only valid when confirm_time is set.`personal_reocrd` only contains activity_id, `activity` which contains activities' time need to join to sum (time) a person spend.

As a activity is deleted by updating `activity.delete_time` column.

Here is my code.

Update(Almost solved): ($data_begin filter the range of records)

```
$result = $this->db->select('user.*, ifnull(sum(ac.time), 0) as time')
                   ->from('user')
                   ->join('(select * from personal_record where personal_record.confirm_time is not null) as pr','user.id = pr.person', 'left')
                   ->join('(select * from activity where activity.delete_time is null and activity.create_time >"'.$date_begin.'")as ac','ac.id = pr.activity', 'left')
                   ->group_by('user.id')
                   ->order_by('time', 'desc')
                   ->get()
                   ->result();
```

Comment: Remove where condition and add it into on condition like this  ->join('activity','activity.id = personal_record.activity and activity.delete_time=NULL ', 'left', false) @teek

Comment: You should look into this question, maybe it help. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056303/combining-mysql-and-or-queries-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('user.*,personal_record.*,ifnull(sum(activity.time), 0) as time');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('personal_record','personal_record.person = user.id');
$this->db->join('activity','activity.id = personal_record.activity');
$this->db->where('activity.delete_time',null);
$this->db->or_where('personal_record.confirm_time !=', null);
$this->db->order_by('time', 'asc');
$this->db->group_by('user.id');
$data = $this->db->get()->result();
return $data;
```

Comment: using `where` will filter some users as they didn't take part in any activities.